# New gas line and permits for new tankless hot water heater

Tags: plumbing, gas, natural-gas

My partner and I have a small home in the SF Bay Area. To try to reclaim some indoor space, we're planning on replacing our tank water heater (currently in the house) with a tankless unit that we're going to put outside.

The company we're planning on going with has given us quotes with and without permits. The price with permits costs $1,300 more partly because they said the inspector/code will require them to run a dedicated gas line to handle the tankless unit even though our existing gas line has enough capacity. I don't mind the charge as much as I mind having a potentially unnecessary, unsightly gas line that requires drywall to be ripped/replaced in a finished room in order to route the gas line. (Our house has no crawl space.)

While I generally prefer to do things with permits to make sure the job is done well/safely, I realize building code doesn't always make sense, and we've had our share of bad experiences with overzealous inspectors.

I'd love people's advice on the following:

1. Do we have enough natural gas capacity in our house to support a new tankless hot water heater and our other gas appliances (HVAC furnace, dryer)? I believe we have a 1" supply line, although I measured a 4.5" circumference or 1.43" OD for the gas supply line, which doesn't match the expected OD for a 1" or a 1.25" gas supply line.
2. Is it true that building code would require us to get a new gas line regardless of the sizing of the current gas lines we have?
3. If you were getting this work done, would you get a permit pulled for this work?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide!

**EDIT:** I looked up the BTU/hr. ratings of my dryer and furnace. They are 18,500 and 60,000, respectively. The two tankless models I'm considering (Navien NPE-210A2 and NPE-240A2) have 180k and 199k BTU/hr. ratings. Given what I see [here](http://snowcrest.net/thriftysupply/pdf/NAT-LP-PIPE-SIZE.pdf) and the runs of gas line that we have/will have (20-40 feet), it's going to be pretty close. If I want to run everything at once (unlikely), we would need a new line.

**EDIT 2:** Clarified the reason behind the new gas line (required by inspector/code) and that the bigger issue for me is having an additional gas line and having to replace drywall vs. price.

**EDIT 3:** I located the meter under the sidewalk and took a picture. It appears to be a "Sprague 175" gas meter. I also bought a pair of calipers and measured the line coming out of the meter (vs. gas lines in my home). It appears to have a OD of 1.0685", which corresponds to a 3/4" gas line.

[image: Sprague 175][image: 3/4" gas line]

**EDIT 4:** More updates. According to PG&E (gas supplier):

> Upon review of your address, we see that the gas service is for 425k btu's or less. Are you adding need appliances that will increase your load? If you need a larger gas service at the location please submit the application below

I also asked my tankless WH person about my findings re: the 3/4" supply line and whether I would still need a dedicated line. His response:

> You would still need a dedicated line from that tee in your garage to the tankless. It is unnecessary which is why I have issues with pulling permits on something like this, but they will require it.
>
> If pge got involved they’d want you to have the meter moved in your garage as they are not allowing sidewalk mounted meters anymore.

Comment: What else uses gas? How much? can all things run together?

Comment: You may want to consult an attorney about the liability you might face by making unpermitted changes to your home before attempting this.

Comment: @SolarMike Only dryer and furnace. Not sure if all things can run together.

Comment: As for your 1.43" OD measurement. Was this measured with calipers? Nominal 1" black iron should have an actual O.D. of  1.315" and nominal 1.25" should be 1.660". I would be really surprised if you had something which is in between these two pipe sizes; 1.125" pipe seems exotic.

Comment: Relocating the tankless WH to the outside gives two huge benefits. First, there is no flue that penetrates the ceiling and roof. (The exhaust comes directly out of a slit near the top of the unit.) Second, if it ever leaks it will not dump water inside.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it does seem very unusual. It was a rough measurement using measuring tape. I'm looking to buy a pair of calipers and redo the measurement, but I'm assuming for now it's probably a 1" pipe.

Comment: Without knowing the details of your gas meter it's impossible to tell you whether or not you have enough supply. Take a picture of your meter outside and share it. It probably has a model number like AC-250 or something.

Comment: Use a 160 kBTU/h WH, or even 140 kBTU/h, if that would satisfy the city inspectors. I think 199 is certainly way more than you need and 180 probably more than you need. A 160 kBTU/h unit should be able to heat water for two people. Fourteen years ago we put in a Bosch 125 NG tankless WH with output 120 kBTU/h and it works for two people. I elected to just use the same gas line as that fed the 40 gal NG fired tank. This is an inside model and I had the installer place the tankless WH on the wall where the tank had been. The WH shares a 3/4" gas line with a 100 kBTU/h natural gas furnace.

Comment: Do you have a central air conditioner? What is the size of your electric service, 100 A,  125 A, 150 A . . . ? How old is your gas furnace? Is this a forced air system with ducting of the air from a central air handler? Or is it baseboard radiators heated by circulating hot water? Is the incoming city water extremely cold? Do you know the temp of your incoming city water?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus AFIK any gas supplier will change the meter to one with a larger max supply rate if the customer documents a need. The problem is usually the size of the underground gas line from the meter to the structure and the the size of the lines inside the structure. OP my questions above relate to whether you could ultimately change to heat with an electrically powered heat pump.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus AFIK any gas supplier will change the meter to one with a larger max supply rate if the customer documents a need. The problem is usually the size of the underground gas line from the meter to the structure and the the size of the lines inside the structure. OP my questions above relate to whether you could ultimately change to space heating with an electrically powered heat pump. Of course, that might produce objectionable noise outside. A quiet outside space might be important.

Comment: Would the city inspectors allow you to keep your existing gas line if you would reduce the size of the tankless heater to 140 kBTU/h?

Comment: @JimStewart No central air. 100A electrical. Gas furnace is relatively old forced air system. Ground water is supposedly 57F per the US map.

Comment: @JimStewart Good call on the size of the underground gas line - while I appear to have larger gas lines in the house itself, the underground gas line from the meter is 3/4". Re: the city inspectors, I've mostly entrusted the company who has advised me the city will ask for a new gas line, but I can double check.

Comment: Be advised that AFIK all modern tankless WHs require 120 V to function.  So if you have frequent power outages and it is important to you to always have hot water available, a tankless WH is problematic. A gas fired tank will of course supply hot water when the power is off, and can cope with 57F inlet water, but you want the inside space the tank is occupying. You have got a lot of constraints. Our decision to go tankless was made by my partner. I would indefinitely ponder the matter and when faced with replacement get another tank.

Comment: @JimStewart Not true. Suppliers try to keep residences to 1/4" PSI so if more gas is needed they will first suggest to upsize the main line coming into the home. This prevents homeowners from needing natural gas regulators for all their appliances. Gas on the street leading up to your meter can be as high as 60 PSI so that they don't need obnoxiously large lines underground. If you're nice they might agree to bump your PSI to 1/2" if you can prove that the proper regulator will be installed where needed. Usually a licensed plumber is required to make such a request though.

Comment: I see you've added some pictures. The Sprague 175 seems to be rated for 175K BTU. You're instant hot water will take all of these BTUs and you should avoid running your furnace or dryer while someone is using hot water. A new gas line is the right answer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I appreciate your correction of my comment but I am unclear on exactly what was wrong. In Dallas all residences are supplied by a meter which reduces the gas main pressure to 0.25 psig. AFIK I have never heard of any possibility that the gas supplier would or could reset the pressure regulator to anywhere near 0.5 psig.  I know that there is a totally new system which delivers gas at something like 2 psig, but this is for new construction, and requires regulators for each gas outlet or connected appliance.

Comment: For a qualified gas tech changing a gas meter is simple and the gas supplier does it at no charge to the customer. In Dallas replacing an underground line from the meter to the structure costs the homeowner $$$. If the existing underground line and the lines in the structure cannot carry more gas than the existing meter, then there is no point in getting a larger meter. But if the meter is the limiting factor then surely the supplier will install a larger meter, right?

Comment: OP, given what has been said it seems you should contact the city or the gas supplier and ask them if your existing gas piping and gas meter are capable of supplying gas at the rate a tankless  WH would require. It seems not.  Note there is a misconception that tankless WHs provide *instant hot water*. This is not the case.

Comment: @JimStewart My bad. I must have missed "underground gas line **from the meter to the structure**" initially. Yes, your comment is correct.

Comment: @JimStewart Thanks for all your help. I've added more info that I received from the gas supplier and the person I've been talking to re: swapping out my tankless WH.

Comment: Also @MonkeyZeus (StackExchange won't let me tag multiple people at once.)

Comment: Have you given any thought to what may happen when you want to sell your house and the buyer wants to bring in an inspector?

Comment: OP, does your meter supply gas to your lines at 0.25 psig? Sometimes the gas pressure is given in units of inches of water column and 0.25 psig = 7 inch WC. The "g" in psig stands for "gauge" meaning that this is the pressure *relative* to atmospheric but often people leave off the g.

Comment: @JimStewart No idea. How would I figure that out? Asking the utility company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locating a gas fired tankless WH outside gives two huge benefits. First, there is no flue that penetrates the ceiling and roof. The exhaust comes directly out of a slit near the top of the unit. The combustion air also comes directly from the outside air as opposed to an inside location where provision must be made to supply combustion air.

Second, if it ever leaks it will not dump water inside. And the regular descaling operation with vinegar is easier outside.

All, or nearly all, modern gas fired tankless WHs require 120 V a/c power to operate the electronic controls and to power a small heater to prevent freezing of the core when ambient temp drops below freezing.

Part of the cost of installing a tankless WH outside is the cost of installing an outside 120 V receptacle if there is not one where you want to place the WH. The outside location is best suited to a climate with little or no freezing weather, but a proper installation can work in a climate with some freezing weather.

EDIT

I recommend getting the permit and city inspection in spite of the extra charge.

EDIT'

Most houses require a whole house tankless WH with a burner rated at 160 kBTU/h to 180 kBTU/h to replace a 50 gal tank. Such a tank will have a burner rated at about 40 kBTU/h and the original gas line will be too small for the tankless WH.

In some houses the gas plumbing with black iron pipe has a capped off "T" to provide a connection point for future gas appliances. A new 3/4" line from that "T" to the tankless WH would be necessary and sufficient to allow full function of the WH.

EDIT''

I suggest you use a 160 kBTU/h tankless WH if that would satisfy the city inspectors, and let you use the existing gas line. That should be able to heat water for two people. Fourteen years ago we put in a Bosch 125 NG tankless WH with output 120 kBTU/h and it works for two people. I elected to just use the same gas line as that fed the 40 gal NG fired tank.  This is an inside model and I had the installer place the tankless WH on the wall where the tank had been. The WH shares a 3/4" gas line with a 100 kBTU/h natural gas furnace.

Comment: Hi Jim - thanks for the extensive reply! Agreed with the benefits re: moving the WH outside, although we will still have to run a outdoor vent to the roof because of how close the WH will be to the property.

I'm not as worried about the extra charge as much as I am about having a potentially unsightly, unnecessary gas line + having to rip and replace dry wall in a finished laundry room to route it.

We fortunately have a 3/4" gas line where the current 40-gal tank WH and furnace are.

Comment: I have never seen a tankless WH designed for outside placement that had a round flue going up. All the ones I have seen have a slit on the outside face.  I used to visit a relative in Oakland CA that had one like that, i.e., slit without a flue. Is your house very close to a neighbor's house or is it that the only good location is close to a window on your house? If you are going to have a roof penetration, get a roofer to do that part. A plumber is likely to do the flashing wrong

Comment: Looks like the Navien models you are looking at are rated for inside or outside placement so a vertical flue outside is an option. My choice of a tankless model was made 15 yo  while standing in a checkout line at HD. Next to me were two boxes with a sign over them "Discontinued model Bosch tankless WH, price reduced". I took both and had one installed in my house and one in a relative's. In both cases we used the original gas lines which had been feeding a 40 kBTU/h tank. This is a basic unit with mechanical controls and standing pilot light! No mains electricity reqd. But you cannot do that.

Comment: I have been told that modern tankless water heaters have a gas pressure sensor and will not come on if the gas pressure is below a certain value. If you would decide to use your existing gas lines, it *could be* that when your gas furnace lights up the gas pressure at the water heater would drop below the lower limit. Last summer we replaced our 30 yo HVAC/gas furnace with one that has extensive electronic controls. Our 120 kBTU/h tankless WH and this 100 kBTU/h furnace share a 3/4" gas line from a central point in the attic. The furnace worked perfectly in last winter's 0 F cold.

Comment: The conclusion of the above is that your contractor may be correct that your existing gas lines will acceptably feed a 160 kBTU/h tankless WH. The city inspectors may be insisting on unnecessarily large gas lines. Our house has a 1" line* from the meter up into a central point in the attic. From that point there is maybe 12 ft of 3/4" black gas pipe. *OD measured with Vernier calipers 33.4 mm = 1.315 inch.

Comment: What is the length of pipe from your meter to where you want to place the tankless WH? You might want to look at tables that show how much gas a gas pipe system can carry.

Comment: Just realized there are a ton of comments here I missed. My house is attached to the neighbor's, so the tankless WH is going within 3-4 ft. of the property line. Interesting story with getting a discounted tankless WH - I def. would have been too nervous re: whether it would work with my place to do something so spontaneous! The length of pipe is probably going to be something around 30-40 ft. I'm pretty sure that the 3/4" pipe that comes into the house stubs up and becomes a 1" pipe.